# Tag for "meta-knowledge" puzzles

Tags: discussion, tags

There's a large class of puzzles where a group of people, often described as perfect logicians, are put in a situation where they have to deduce things based on what they know, and what they know others know, and so on. 
 Examples:

- Blue-eyed islanders
- Sum and product
- Cheryl's Birthday
- Some hat puzzles (not the team-strategy ones)

So far, only the blue-eyes puzzles have their own tag. I feel like there should be a tag that encompasses all of these, like [meta-knowledge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-knowledge) or [common-knowledge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-knowledge) (I personally prefer the former). I'd of course go through and do the retagging.

Does anyone disagree with this? Or have opinions about the tag name?

Comment: Inductive knowledge?

Comment: The mathematical term would perhaps be "Reasoning About Knowledge", which is much too long for a tag name; see https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/reasoning-about-knowledge . I like "common-knowledge".

Comment: @Gamow When I hear "common knowledge," I think "commonplace," as in, "stuff that everyone should know."  Consider a sentence like, "It's common knowledge that you're only supposed to cross a street on a green light."  Thus I think it's a poor choice for this context due to its likelihood of being misinterpreted.

Comment: Then `shared-knowledge` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a great idea - the puzzle type is fairly common, and I'm surprised we don't already had a tag for it. As for the tag name itself, any of these would work well:

- [meta-logic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-logic)
- [common-knowledge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-knowledge)
- [knowledge-simulation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge-simulation)

(Thanks to Gamow for the second one.)

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer meta-logic over meta-knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

- [epistemology](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epistemology) ?

+1 for @BenVoigt's suggestion [shared-knowledge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shared-knowledge)